# Confused on how Prolog assigns values. Why doesn't Prolog bind X when there isn't any parenthesis?

Tags: variables, prolog, operator-precedence

I'm using SWI for Windows and I'm trying out an exercise in Learn Prolog Now!

```
travel(Start,Dest,X) :-
    (byCar(Start,Dest); byTrain(Start,Dest); byPlane(Start,Dest)),
    X = go(Start,Dest).
```

In this code if the you can reach Dest from Start, Prolog says:

*true.*

*X = go(Start,Dest).*

and just says false otherwise.

However in this code when I removed the parenthesis it only says true if valid and false if invalid. The answer is correct but why doesn't it output X?

```
travel(Start,Dest,X) :-
    byCar(Start,Dest); byTrain(Start,Dest); byPlane(Start,Dest),
    X = go(Start,Dest).
```

Is it because of operator precedence in which AND gets evaluated first? Even if thats the case shouldn't X still be equal to go(Start,Dest)?

The way Prolog assigns values to variables confuses me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're right, precedence of and is lower that or. When unsure, you can use [write_canonical](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=write_canonical/1)

```
4 ?- write_canonical((travel(Start,Dest,X) :-
    byCar(Start,Dest); byTrain(Start,Dest); byPlane(Start,Dest),
    X = go(Start,Dest))).
:-(travel(A,B,C),;(byCar(A,B),;(byTrain(A,B),','(byPlane(A,B),=(C,go(A,B))))))
true.

5 ?- write_canonical((travel(Start,Dest,X) :-
    (byCar(Start,Dest); byTrain(Start,Dest); byPlane(Start,Dest)),
    X = go(Start,Dest))).
:-(travel(A,B,C),','(;(byCar(A,B),;(byTrain(A,B),byPlane(A,B))),=(C,go(A,B))))
true.
```

and [current_op](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=current_op/3) to check beforehand

```
6 ?- current_op(P,A,(,)).
P = 1000,
A = xfy.

7 ?- current_op(P,A,(;)).
P = 1100,
A = xfy.
```

Comment: @WillNess: Prolog use `precedence` to name the first argument of op/3. And the order is as shown...

Answer (score 1):

you first code is equivalent to

```
travel(Start,Dest,X) :- byCar(Start,Dest), X = go(Start,Dest).
travel(Start,Dest,X) :- byTrain(Start,Dest), X = go(Start,Dest).
travel(Start,Dest,X) :- byPlane(Start,Dest), X = go(Start,Dest).
```

if any of the `byNNN` predicate succeed, whatever bindings they produced for their arguments will be reflected by `X`'s binding. If you see `X = go(Start,Dest)` as the output, it means that `byNNN` succeeded without instantiating its arguments.

the second is equivalent to

```
travel(Start,Dest,X) :- byCar(Start,Dest).
travel(Start,Dest,X) :- byTrain(Start,Dest).
travel(Start,Dest,X) :- byPlane(Start,Dest), X = go(Start,Dest).
```

so when it succeeds by way of its first or second clause, it doesn't involve `X` at all.